# МНК алгоритм

Tags: алгоритм, c++, численные-методы

Метод наименьших квадратов

Задача написать алгоритм для нахождения коэффициентов полинома N степени с помощью МНК по M точек. То есть даны 10 точек, и сказано аппроксимировать для полинома 3-й степени:

```
y=ax^3 + a1x^2 + a2x+a3
```

Для этого полинома надо найти a, a1, a2, a3; если для 1 и 2 степени можно написать вручную, то даже для 3-й степени придётся решать систему 4-х уравнений с 4 неизвестными.

Вот [тут](http://mathhelpplanet.com/static.php?p=onlayn-mnk-i-regressionniy-analiz) можно посмотреть, как выглядит аппроксимация для разных функций с помощью мнк.

Как запрограммировать алгоритм, который будет составлять СЛОУ и решать её?

Язык c++.

**Обновление**

Как в составлении так и в решении. Начал решать пока что такая система получается для полинома N степени. `Ex` сумма от 1 до `M` (кол-во точек).

```
a1*Ex^n     + a2*Ex^n - 1  + ... + an*Ex^0=Eyx^0

a1*Ex^n + 1 + a2*Ex^n      + ... + an*Ex^1=Eyx^1
```

---

```
a1*Ex^2n    + a2*Ex^2n - 1 + ... + an*Ex^n=Eyx^n
```

Даже после того как перепишу все известные `Ex,Ey,Exy`... в массив, то я незнаю как решать такую СЛАУ

**Решение**

Прошу меня простить за кривые отступы.
Функция которая находит коэф. полинома N степени

```
    vector<double>* mnk(vector<vector<double>> pts,int n,int n2)  
    {
        //матрица хранящая неизвестные при нужных нам коэффициентах 
        vector<vector<double>> linSys(n + 1);
double tmp=0;
vector<double> subsid(3*n + 2);//почему 3n + 2? да потому что http://mathhelpplanet.com/static.php?p=onlayn - mnk - i - regressionniy - analiz
for (int i=0;i<2*n + 1;i ++ )//этот цикл формирует первую половину (точнее 2/3) списка величин x^0 x^1...x^2n + 1
{
    for (int j=0;j<n2;j ++ )
    {
        tmp + =pow(pts[j][0],i);
    }
    subsid[i]=tmp;
    tmp=0;
}
for (int i=2*n + 1;i<3*n + 2;i ++ )//этот цикл формирует вторую половину  списка величин x^0*y x^1*y...x^n*y
{
    for (int j=0;j<n2;j ++ )
    {
        tmp + =pow(pts[j][0],i - 2*n - 1)*pts[j][1];
    }
    subsid[i]=tmp;
    tmp=0;
}
//тут уже идёт формирование СЛАУ получаем матрицу linSys
//a1*Ex^n      +  a2*Ex^n  -  1   +  ...  +  an*Ex^0=Eyx^0
//a1*Ex^n  +  1  +  a2*Ex^n       +  ...  +  an*Ex^1=Eyx^1
//  ...            ...         ...       ... 
//a1*Ex^2n     +  a2*Ex^2n  -  1  +  ...  +  an*Ex^n=Eyx^n
//Будем решать СЛАУ в виде A*x=b
//в моем случае linSys*x=b
vector<double>*b=new vector<double>;
b - >resize(n + 1);
for(int i = 0; i < n  +  1; i ++ )
{
    linSys[i].resize(n + 1);
    (*b)[i]=subsid[2*n + 1 + i];
    for(int j=0;j<n + 1;j ++ )
    {
        linSys[i][j]=subsid[n + i - j];
    }

}
vector<double>*x=new vector<double>;
x - >resize(n + 1);
//это решает СЛАУ и пишет результ в x
Gauss(linSys,*b,x,n + 1);
return x;
```

}

Функция которая решает СЛАУ

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
//результат записывает в x, СЛАУ представима как A*x=B
void Gauss(vector<vector<double>> A, vector<double> b, vector<double> *x, int n)
    {
std::stack<std::pair<size_t,size_t> > swaps;
int i, j, k, t;
double kof, s;
for (i = n  -  1; i > 0;  -- i) {
    for (t=i, j=i - 1; j >= 0;  -- j) {//Поиск максимума в столбце
        if (fabs(A[i][t]) < fabs(A[i][j])) {
            t = j;
        }
    }
    if (A[i][t] == 0.0) {
        return;
    }
    if (t != i) {
        for (k = n  -  1; k >= 0;  -- k) {
            std::swap(A[k][t],A[k][i]);
        }
        swaps.push(std::pair<size_t, size_t>(i,t));
    }
    for (j=i - 1; j>=0;  -- j) {//
        kof = A[j][i] / A[i][i];//
        A[j][i] = 0.0;//
        b[j]  - = b[i] * kof;
        for (k = i  -  1; k >= 0;  -- k) {
            A[j][k]  - = A[i][k] * kof;
        }
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < n;  ++ i)
{
    s = 0.0;
    for (j = i  -  1; j >= 0;  -- j) {
        s  + = A[i][j] * (*x)[j];
    }
    (*x)[i] = (b[i]  -  s) / A[i][i];
}
while (!swaps.empty()) {
    //int j=swaps.top().first;
//  int y=swaps.top().second;
    std::swap((*x)[swaps.top().first], (*x)[swaps.top().second]);
    swaps.pop();
}
```

}

Comment: Конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос. В чем затруднения? В решении системы уравнений или в ее составлении?

Answer (score 12):

Задача о полиномиальной регрессии (аппроксимации табличной функции) требует большой аккуратности, поскольку при обычных методах решения расчёт главного определителя СЛАУ (определителя Вандермонда) приводит к вычитанию близких чисел и в итоге снижает относительную погрешность вычислений, что проявляется уже для полиномов `8-10` порядка.

От этих недостатков свободны методы разложения в ряды по ортогональным функциям (например, разложение в ряды Фурье по косинусам), и хотелось бы так же просто обращаться с полиномами. Однако классические ортогональные полиномы (Лежандра, Чебышёва и пр.) в дискретном варианте ортогональны только на специально подобранных неравномерных сетках.

Удачный выход из такой ситуации даёт малоизвестный метод ортогональной полиномиальной регрессии ([Orthogonal Polynomial Curve Fitting, Jeff Reid](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYw4eXg9HSAhXPKiwKHRJBBU0QFghXMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjeffareid.net%2Fmisc%2Fopls.rtf&usg=AFQjCNHuzP-Q0c5BABak1M7NhxKN29Gr0w&sig2=N6J8HAijGQOuA6qJrOJc3A&bvm=bv.149397726,d.bGg)), в котором сначала по абсциссам заданных точек конструируются ортогональные полиномы, а затем с помощью МНК рассчитываются коэффициенты при этих полиномах.

**1. ТЕОРИЯ**

**1.1. Постановка задачи**

Даны **n** точек **{ (x<sub>i</sub>,y<sub>i</sub>), i = 0, 1 ... n-1 }**.
Найти полином **g(x) = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>x + ... + a<sub>m</sub>x<sup>m</sup>** с минимальной суммой **∑<sub>i = 0, 1 ... n-1</sub> (y<sub>i</sub> - g(x<sub>i</sub>))<sup>2</sup>** среди всеx возможных полиномов **n**-го порядка.

Решение будем искать в виде **g(x) = b<sub>0</sub> p<sub>0</sub>(x) + b<sub>1</sub> p<sub>1</sub>(x) + ... + b<sub>m</sub> p<sub>m</sub>(x),**
где **p<sub>j</sub>(x), j = 0, 1, ... m** - семейство ортогональных полиномов, для которых должны выполняться рекуррентные соотношения

**p<sub>j+1</sub>(x) = (x-A<sub>j+1</sub>) p<sub>j</sub>(x) -  B<sub>j</sub> p<sub>j-1</sub>(x), p<sub>0</sub>(x) = 1, p<sub>-1</sub>(x) = 0,** (1)

и условия ортогональности

**∑<sub>i = 0, 1 ... n-1</sub> p<sub>j</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) p<sub>k</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) = 0**  при  **j ≠ k**. (2)

**1.2. Построение ортогональных полиномов.**

Для `j = 0` формулы `(1)` и `(2)` дают:  **p<sub>1</sub>(x) = x - A<sub>1</sub>**,  *∑ (x<sub>i</sub> - A<sub>1</sub>) = 0*, откуда

**A<sub>1</sub> = ∑x<sub>i</sub> / n.**

Если для `j = 0 ... k` ортогональные полиномы *p<sub>j</sub>* уже известны, то следующий полином **p<sub>k+1</sub>** должен быть ортогонален каждому из них:  *∑ p<sub>j</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) p<sub>k+1</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) = 0.*  Используя рекурррентные соотношения `(1)`, получаем:

**∑ x<sub>i</sub> p<sub>j</sub> (x<sub>i</sub>) p<sub>k</sub> (x<sub>i</sub>) - A<sub>k+1</sub>∑ p<sub>j</sub> (x<sub>i</sub>) p<sub>k</sub> (x<sub>i</sub>) - B<sub>k</sub>∑ p<sub>j</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) p<sub>k-1</sub> (x<sub>i</sub>) = 0,**  (3)

**xp<sub>j</sub>(x) = p<sub>j+1</sub>(x) + A<sub>j+1</sub>p<sub>j</sub>(x) +  B<sub>j</sub> p<sub>j-1</sub>(x),**  (1')

Из условий `(2)` и `(1')` следует, что для `j = 0 ... k-2` все три слагаемых в соотношениях `(3)` нулевые. При `j = k - 1` условия ортогональности уничтожают второе слагаемое в формуле `(3)` и два младших слагаемых в `(1')`, поэтому

**B<sub>k</sub> = ∑ p<sup>2</sup><sub>k</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) / ∑ p<sup>2</sup><sub>k-1</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>).**  (4)

В случае `j = k` условия ортогональности обнуляют третье слагаемое в формуле `(3)`, поэтому

**A<sub>k+1</sub> = ∑ x<sub>i</sub>p<sup>2</sup><sub>k</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) / ∑ p<sup>2</sup><sub>k</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>).**  (5)

**1.3. Построение полинома регрессии**

Метод наименьших квадратов для полинома
**g(x) = b<sub>0</sub>p<sub>0</sub>(x) + b<sub>1</sub>p<sub>1</sub>(x) + ... + b<sub>m</sub>p<sub>m</sub>(x)**
предполагает вычисление коэффициентов *b<sub>j</sub>*, `j = 0 ... m`, по методу наименьших квадратов, т.е. минимизацию функции невязки
**F(b<sub>0</sub>, b<sub>1</sub> ... b<sub>m</sub>) = ∑ (y<sub>i</sub> - b<sub>0</sub>p<sub>0</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) - b<sub>1</sub>p<sub>1</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) - ... - b<sub>m</sub>p<sub>m</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>))<sup>2</sup>**
по этим коэффициентам, рассматриваемым в качестве переменных. При этом в точке минимума должны выполняться необходимые условия экстремума, т.е. равенство нулю частных производных *F'<sub>b<sub>k</sub></sub>(b<sub>0</sub>, b<sub>1</sub> ... b<sub>m</sub>)*:

**-2∑ (y<sub>i</sub> - b<sub>0</sub>p<sub>0</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) - b<sub>1</sub>p<sub>1</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) - ... - b<sub>m</sub>p<sub>m</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>)) p<sub>k</sub> = 0**,  `k = 0 ... m`.

Разбивая каждое из этих уравнений на слагаемые и используя условия ортогональности `(2)`, получим:
**∑ y<sub>i</sub>p<sub>k</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) - b<sub>k</sub> ∑ p<sub>k</sub><sup>2</sup>(x<sub>i</sub>) = 0**,  `k = 0 ... m`,

**b<sub>k</sub> = ∑ y<sub>i</sub>p<sub>k</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>) / ∑ p<sub>k</sub><sup>2</sup>(x<sub>i</sub>)**,  `k = 0 ... m`. (6)

Приводя полином `g(x)` к виду
**g(x) = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub>x + ... + a<sub>m</sub>x<sup>m</sup>,**
получим:
**a<sub>j</sub> = ∑<sub>k=j...m</sub> b<sub>k</sub> p<sub>kj</sub>**,  `j = 0 ... m`. (7)

Формулы `(6-7)` позволяют построить алгоритм расчёта коэффициентов 
**a<sub>j</sub>**  полинома **g(x)**, если ортогональные полиномы известны.

**2. АЛГОРИТМ**

**2.1. Значения ортогональных полиномов в узлах сетки**

Значения полиномов *P<sub>j</sub><sub>i</sub> = p<sub>i</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>)* в узлах сетки можно вычислить по формулам `(1,4-5)`:

**P<sub>0</sub><sub>i</sub> = 1,** 
**P<sub>1</sub><sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i</sub> -  Q<sub>0</sub> / S<sub>0</sub>,** 
**P<sub>j+1,i</sub> = (x<sub>i</sub> -  Q<sub>j</sub> / S<sub>j</sub>) P<sub>j,i</sub> - (S<sub>j</sub> / S<sub>j-1</sub>) P<sub>j-1,i</sub>** `для j > 0`,

где **S<sub>j</sub> = ∑<sub>i</sub> P<sub>j,i</sub><sup>2</sup>, Q<sub>j</sub> = ∑<sub>i</sub> x<sub>i</sub> P<sub>j,i</sub><sup>2</sup>.**

Для полинома третьего порядка (`m=3`) алгоритм имеет вид:

**P<sub>0i</sub> = 1;  S<sub>0</sub> = m+1;  Q<sub>0</sub> = ∑ x<sub>i</sub>,**

**P<sub>1i</sub> = x<sub>i</sub> - Q<sub>0</sub> / S<sub>0</sub>;  S<sub>1</sub> = ∑ (P<sub>1i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>;  Q<sub>1</sub> = ∑ x<sub>i</sub> (P<sub>1i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>,**

**P<sub>2i</sub> = (x<sub>i</sub> - Q<sub>1</sub> / S<sub>1</sub>) P<sub>1i</sub> - S<sub>1</sub> / S<sub>0</sub>;  S<sub>2</sub> = ∑ (P<sub>2i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>;  Q<sub>2</sub> = ∑ x<sub>i</sub> (P<sub>2i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>,**

**P<sub>3i</sub> = (x<sub>i</sub> - Q<sub>2</sub> / S<sub>2</sub>) P<sub>2i</sub> - S<sub>2i</sub> / S<sub>1i</sub>;  S<sub>3</sub> = ∑ (P<sub>3i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>;  Q<sub>3</sub> = ∑ x<sub>i</sub> (P<sub>3i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>.**

**2.2. Коэффициенты ортогональных полиномов**

Рекуррентные формулы `(1,4,5)` также позволяют вычислить все коэффициенты **с<sub>kj</sub>** ортогональных полиномов вида *p<sub>k</sub>(x) = с<sub>k0</sub> + с<sub>k1</sub> x + ... + с<sub>kj</sub> x<sup>j</sup> +... + с<sub>km</sub> x<sup>m</sup>*, которые в общем случае представляют собой алгебраическую сумму трёх величин:

**с<sub>k+1,j</sub> = с<sub>k,j-1</sub> - (Q<sub>k</sub> / S<sub>k</sub>) с<sub>k,j</sub> - (S<sub>k</sub> / S<sub>k-1</sub>) с<sub>k-1,j</sub>** `для k = 0, 1 ... m-1`, `j = 0, 1, ... , k`,

**с<sub>k,k</sub> = 1** для  `k = 0, 1 ... m`.

Первое слагаемое не следует учитывать при `j = 0`, третье - при `j = k`.

Для полинома третьего порядка (`m=3`):

**с<sub>00</sub> = 1,  с<sub>10</sub> = - Q<sub>0</sub> / S<sub>0</sub>;  с<sub>11</sub> = 1,**

**с<sub>20</sub> = - (Q<sub>2</sub> / S<sub>2</sub>) с<sub>10</sub> - (S<sub>1</sub> / S<sub>0</sub>) с<sub>00</sub>;**  
**с<sub>21</sub> = с<sub>10</sub> - (Q<sub>2</sub> / S<sub>2</sub>) с<sub>11</sub> - (S<sub>1</sub> / S<sub>0</sub>) с<sub>01</sub>;** 
**с<sub>22</sub> = 1,**

**с<sub>30</sub> = - (Q<sub>3</sub> / S<sub>3</sub>) с<sub>20</sub> - (S<sub>2</sub> / S<sub>1</sub>) с<sub>10</sub>;** 
**с<sub>31</sub> = с<sub>20</sub> - (Q<sub>3</sub> / S<sub>3</sub>) с<sub>21</sub> - (S<sub>2</sub> / S<sub>1</sub>) с<sub>11</sub>;** 
**с<sub>32</sub> = с<sub>21</sub> - (Q<sub>3</sub> / S<sub>3</sub>) с<sub>22</sub> - (S<sub>2</sub> / S<sub>1</sub>) с<sub>12</sub>;**  
**с<sub>33</sub> = 1.**

**2.3. Коэффициенты полинома регрессии.**

Коэффициенты *b<sub>k</sub>* в разложении *g(x) = b<sub>0</sub> p<sub>0</sub>(x) + b<sub>1</sub> p<sub>1</sub>(x) + ... + b<sub>m</sub> p<sub>m</sub>(x)* вычисляются в соответствии с `(6)` по формулам

**b<sub>k</sub> = ∑<sub>i</sub> y<sub>i</sub> P<sub>ki</sub> / S<sub>k</sub>**,  `k = 0 ... m`.

Для полинома третьего порядка:

**b<sub>0</sub> = ∑<sub>i</sub> y<sub>i</sub> P<sub>0i</sub> / S<sub>0</sub>**, 
**b<sub>1</sub> = ∑<sub>i</sub> y<sub>i</sub> P<sub>1i</sub> / S<sub>1</sub>**, 
**b<sub>2</sub> = ∑<sub>i</sub> y<sub>i</sub> P<sub>2i</sub> / S<sub>2</sub>**, 
**b<sub>3</sub> = ∑<sub>i</sub> y<sub>i</sub> P<sub>3i</sub> / S<sub>3</sub>**.

Коэффициенты *a<sub>j</sub>* в разложении *g(x) = a<sub>0</sub> + a<sub>1</sub> x + ... + a<sub>m</sub> x<sup>m</sup>* вычисляются по формуле
**a<sub>j</sub> = ∑ <sub>k=j...m</sub> b<sub>k</sub> с<sub>kj</sub>**,  `j = 0 ... m`. (7)

Для полинома третьего порядка (`m=3`):

**a<sub>0</sub> = b<sub>0</sub> с<sub>00 +</sub> b<sub>1</sub> с<sub>10</sub> + b<sub>2</sub> с<sub>20</sub> + b<sub>3</sub> с<sub>30</sub>,**
**a<sub>1</sub> = b<sub>1</sub> с<sub>11</sub> + b<sub>2</sub> с<sub>21</sub> + b<sub>3</sub> с<sub>31</sub>,**
**a<sub>2</sub> = b<sub>2</sub> с<sub>22</sub> + b<sub>3</sub> с<sub>32</sub>,**
**a<sub>3</sub> = b<sub>3</sub>.**

**2.4. Об алгоритме**

Разработанный алгоритм в общем виде применим для аппроксимации заданного массива точек полиномом любого порядка при условии достаточности исходных данных и вычислительных средств.
На примере полинома третьего порядка показано, что никакие СЛАУ при этом решать не требуется.

**3. ТЕСТИРОВАНИЕ АЛГОРИТМА**

Тестирование алгоритма проведено с использованием пакета [MathCAD](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3wZyx_GLwRVVDh6YWRZbVlJN2s).
Для тестирования были выбраны 10-точечные массивы **x** и **y** и полиномиальная модель третьего порядка (см. скриншот).

[image: Расчёт коэффициентов аппроксимирующего полинома по методу ортогональной полиномиальной регрессии.]

Тестирование подтвердило правильность алгоритма.

Сравнение результатов расчёта с функцией `regress()` пакета MathCAD показало, что при одинаковой разрядности расчётов (определяемой исходными данными) алгоритм ортогональной полиномиальной регрессии точнее.

**4. ПРОГРАММА НА PHP**

Программа сoдержит класс `Ortho`, конструктор которого принимает исходные массивы `$x`, `$y` и порядок модели `$m` и рассчитывает регрессионный полином.
Для выдачи рассчитанных величин предусмотрены следующие методы:
`getValues()` - для массива значений ортогональных полиномов в точках `x`;
`getSums()` - для сумм, рассчитанных по этому массиву;
`getAllCoeffs()` - для массивов коэффициентов (`с` - массивы коэффициентов ортогональных регрессионных полиномов; `b` - массив для расчёта регрессии по значениям ортогональных полиномов; `a` - коэффициенты при степенях регрессионного полинома);
`getRegress()` - для значений регрессионного полинома и их невязок по отношению к массиву `$y`.

```
/**
*   Polinomial regression via orthogonal regression polynomials.
*   Author: Yury Negometyanov 
*   21.03.2017 
*/

class Ortho
{
    private $x;
    private $y;
    private $m;
    private $values;
    private $sums;
    private $coeffs;

    public function __construct($xx, $yy, $mm)
    {
        $this->x = $xx;
        $this->y = $yy;
        $this->m = $mm;
        $this->calcValuesSums();
        $this->calcAllCoeffs();
    }

    public function subtract($ar, $subtr)
    {
        if(gettype($subtr) == "array") {
            return array_map(function($val1, $val2){ return $val1 - $val2;}, $ar, $subtr);      
        } else { 
            return array_map(function($val)use($subtr){ return $val - $subtr;}, $ar);       
        }
    }

    public function multi($ar, $mult)
    {
        if($mult == "square") {
            return array_map(function($a){return $a * $a;}, $ar);
        } elseif(gettype($mult) == "array") {
            return array_map(function($a, $b){return $a * $b;}, $ar, $mult);
        } else {
            return array_map(function($val)use($mult){ return $val * $mult;}, $ar);     
        }
    }

    private function calcValuesSums()
    {
        for ($j = -1; $j < $this->m ; $j ++) {
            if(!isset($v)) {
                $v = [array_fill(0, count($this->x), 1.0)];
                $s = [(float)count($this->x)];
                $q = [array_sum($this->x)];
            } else {
                $v[] = $this->subtract($this->x, end($q)/end($s)); 
                if($j > 0)  {
                    $v[$j+1] = $this->subtract( $this->multi(end($v), prev($v)), 
                                                $this->multi(prev($v), end($s)/prev($s))); 
                }
                $sq = $this->multi(end($v), "square");
                $s[] = array_sum($sq);
                $q[] = array_sum($this->multi($this->x, $sq));
            }
        }
        $this->values = $v;
        $this->sums = ['&sum;P&sup2;'=>$s, '&sum;xP&sup2;'=>$q];
    }

    private function calcOrthoCoeffs()
    {
        $prev = null;
        $ab = array_map(function($ss, $qq)use(&$prev)
        {
            if(is_null($prev)) $bb = 0;
            else $bb = $ss / $prev;
            $prev = $ss;
            return [$qq / $ss, $bb];
        }, reset($this->sums), next($this->sums));
        foreach ($ab as $k => list($aa, $bb)) {
            if(!isset($с)) $с = [[1.0]];
            $с[] = array_fill(0, $k+2, 1.0);
            for ($j=0; $j <= $k; $j++) { 
                $с[$k+1][$j] = ($j==0 ? 0.0 : $с[$k][$j-1]) 
                                - $с[$k][$j] * $aa 
                                - (($j==$k) ? 0.0 : $с[$k-1][$j] * $bb);
            }
        }
        return $с;
    }

    private function calcAllCoeffs()
    {
        $s = reset($this->sums);
        $b = [];
        foreach ($this->values as $key => $v) {
            $b[] = array_sum($this->multi($this->y, $v))/$s[$key];
        }
        $c = $this->calcOrthoCoeffs();
        $m = count($b) - 1;
        $a = array_fill(0, $m+1, 0.0);
        foreach ($a as $j => &$aj) {
            for ($k = $j; $k <= $m; $k++) {
                $aj += $b[$k] * $c[$k][$j]; 
            }
        }
        $this->coeffs = ['c' => $c, 'b'=>$b, 'a'=>$a];
    }

    private function calcRegress($opt ='a')
    {
        switch ($opt) {
            case 'a':
                $rev = array_reverse($this->coeffs['a']);
                $p = [];
                foreach($this->x as $xx) {
                    $sum = 0.0;
                    foreach ($rev as $value) {
                        $sum *= $xx;
                        $sum += $value;
                    }
                    $p[] = $sum;
                }
                break;

            case 'b':   
                foreach ($this->values as $key => $arr) {
                    if(!isset($p)) $p = $this->multi($arr, $this->coeffs['b'][$key]);
                    else $p = $this->subtract($p, $this->multi($arr, - $this->coeffs['b'][$key]));
                }
                break;

            default:
                $p = [];
                break;
        }
        return $p;
    }

    public function getValues() 
    {
        return $this->values;
    }

    public function getSums() 
    {
        return $this->sums;
    }

    public function getAllCoeffs() 
    {
        return $this->coeffs;
    }

    public function getRegress() 
    {
        $values_a = $this->calcRegress('a');
        $values_b = $this->calcRegress('b');
        return [
            'regress_a'=>$values_a,
            'regress_b'=>$values_b,
            'discrep_a'=>array_sum($this->multi($this->subtract($this->y, $values_a), "square")), 
            'discrep_b'=>array_sum($this->multi($this->subtract($this->y, $values_b), "square"))
        ]; 
    }
}

function print_m($text, $arr, $level=0){
    $space = str_repeat("&emsp;", $level++);
    echo "$space<b>$text</b>";
    $flag = false;
    foreach($arr as $value) $flag = $flag || (gettype($value)=="array");
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(gettype($value) != "array") {
            echo $flag ? "<br>$key => $value" : "&emsp;$value";
        } else {
            print_m("<br>$space$key => [", $value, $level);
            echo "&emsp;]";
        }
    }
    $level--;
}   

$x = [0.00000,  3.36588,  3.63719, 0.56448,  -3.02721,  -3.83570, -1.11766,  2.62795,   3.95743,  1.64847];
$y = [3.95610, 74.84479, 89.44289, 6.46668, -14.53888, -34.55881,  1.70531, 43.80101, 109.12940, 18.81613];

/*
$x = [];
for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) { 
    $x[] = (float)5*sin($i);
}

$y = [];    
foreach ($x as $xx) {
    $y[] = (float)sin($xx/2+1);
}

$n = count($x);
$ort = new Ortho($x, $y, $m = 80);
$discrep = $ort->getRegress();

echo "Sample size = $n&emsp; Model Order = $m";
echo "<br>Discrepancy via Powers is: {$discrep['discrep_a']}";
echo "<br>Discrepancy via Ortogonal Regression Polynomials is: {$discrep['discrep_b']}";
*/

$ort = new Ortho($x, $y, $m=3);
print_m("Issue Data:", ['Array_x'=>$x, 'Array_y'=>$y, 'Model Order'=>$m]);
$values = $ort->getValues();
print_m("<br><br>The Orthogonal Regression Polynomials' Values:", $values);
$sums = $ort->getSums();
print_m("<br><br>Calculated Sums:", $sums);
$coeffs = $ort->getAllCoeffs();
print_m("<br><br>Calculation of Polynomials' Coefficients:", $coeffs);
$discrep = $ort->getRegress();
print_m("<br><br>Regression via Powers (a) & via Orthogonal Regression Polynomials (b) :", $discrep);
```

**5. РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ.**

Результаты на тестовой выборке:

```
Issue Data: 
Array_x => [ 0 3.36588 3.63719 0.56448 -3.02721 -3.8357 -1.11766 2.62795 3.95743 1.64847 ] 
Array_y => [ 3.9561 74.84479 89.44289 6.46668 -14.53888 -34.55881 1.70531 43.80101 109.1294 18.81613 ]
Model Order => 3

The Orthogonal Regression Polynomials' Values: 
0 => [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ] 
1 => [ -0.782083 2.583797 2.855107 -0.217603 -3.809293 -4.617783 -1.899743 1.845867 3.175347 0.866387 ] 
2 => [ -7.2281734230875 2.8073623836192 4.6030924341892 -7.1264829728247 3.0992779145833 8.9585998726813 -5.5494580486592 -1.3320551385999 6.9121153510662 -5.1442783729677 ] 
3 => [ 3.6796621840027 -2.8171823354639 3.1956859234941 -3.0255967835539 8.7399448097287 -12.367028020194 15.20316889478 -12.281110609376 12.297473127759 -12.625017191178 ]

Calculated Sums: 
∑P² => [ 10 69.17098425001 328.7768235086 962.75401849569 ] 
∑xP² => [ 7.82083 -27.512890311149 -1.7129366948718 250.39738237352 ]

Calculation of Polynomials' Coefficients: 
c => [  
 0 => [ 1 ]  
 1 => [ -0.782083 1 ]  
 2 => [ -7.2281734230875 -0.38433110143359 1 ]  
 3 => [ 3.6796621840027 -11.983278954678 -0.37912107270775 1 ]  
 4 => [ 20.209167857339 7.9217601883617 -14.812965853531 -0.63920555697172 1 ] ] 
b => [ 29.906462 15.897655646369 2.3791287087584 1.000001267701 ] 
a => [ 3.9560877250835 2.9999883433859 2.0000071554385 1.000001267701 ]

Regression via Powers (a) & via Orthogonal Regression Polynomials (b) : 
regress_a => [ 3.9560877250835 74.844667502068 89.443009253453 6.4666635861522 -14.538829417751 -34.558843534167 1.7053151756382 43.801163134951 109.12933595098 18.816050623593 ] 
regress_b => [ 3.9560877250835 74.844667502068 89.443009253453 6.4666635861522 -14.538829417751 -34.558843534167 1.7053151756382 43.801163134951 109.12933595098 18.816050623593 ]
discrep_a => 6.7210313148693E-8
discrep_b => 6.7210313149619E-8
```

Результаты работы программы на тестовой выборке соответствуют ожидаемым.
На выборке в `n=1000` точек при порядке модели `80` получено:

```
Sample size = 1000  Model Order = 80
Discrepancy via Powers is: 0.3261862533562
Discrepancy via Ortogonal Regression Polynomials is: 4.2188699484271E-26
```

Таким образом, расчёт регрессии через ортогональные полиномы более устойчив по отношению к ошибкам округления.

**6. ВЫВОДЫ.**

1. Алгоритм можно рекомендовать как удачную альтернативу традиционным алгоритмам для полиномиальной регрессии произвольного порядка.
2. Исходные данные и полученные результаты могут быть использованы для отладки на других языках программирования.

Comment: Holy sh........

Comment: @Other and now?

Comment: Теперь Вам нужно лечится от шизофрении :)

Comment: @Other Я начал сам такое делать, а потом нашёл статью... Диагноз подтверждается, доктор? =)

Comment: Вам осталось только рассказать почему мой галстук мне не подошёл и всё, высылаем группу :)

Comment: @Other Для лабы достаточно по-любому =)

Comment: Ого, вот это исследование!

Comment: @VladD Для математика-вычислителя вопрос принципа: почему с синусами можно, а со степенями нельзя? =)

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Я, кстати, не знал того факта, что разложение по степеням численно нестабильно. Ну то есть я понимал, что мономы неортогональны, но сделать из этого нужный вывод не смог без вашей подсказки. Спасибо!

Comment: @VladD Рад, что понравилось. Когда-то я жёстко влетел на СЛАУ 36-го порядка.