# Как используя МНК сделать прогноз?

Tags: php, c++, алгоритм, численные-методы

Как сделать прогноз используя алгоритм предложенным Yuri Negometyanov на php [МНК алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/383716/%D0%9C%D0%9D%D0%9A-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC/639155) ?

Допустим у меня есть массив данных X и Y 10 значений.

```
$x = [0.00000,  3.36588,  3.63719, 0.56448,  -3.02721,  -3.83570, -1.11766,  2.62795,   3.95743,  1.64847];
$y = [3.95610, 74.84479, 89.44289, 6.46668, -14.53888, -34.55881,  1.70531, 43.80101, 109.12940, 18.81613];
```

Я хочу спрогнозировать 11 значение массива Y?

Answer (score 1):

Хотите спрогнозировать в точке X=11?

Ответ Y=2624.112697191445 Вас устроит? Или Вам больше нравится 192.34738788917497? Мало? Есть вариант 22717.405125233458. Отличный вариант, большой...

Если серьезно, то нельзя вот так взять и спрогнозировать значение функции. Для аппроксимации вообще и метода наименьших квадратов в частности для начала нужно зафиксировать вид аппрокисимирующей функции.

Как собираетесь аппроксимировать? По ссылке используют полиномиальную аппроксимацию. Ок. Какой степенью собираетесь аппроксимировать?

Если полиномы, то зачем вам МНК? Чем плохи полином Ньютона или полином Лагранжа?

Кстати, значение 2624.112697191445 - это значение интерполяционного полинома Лагранжа в точке $x=11$. Но этот полином вам не подойдёт - у него явно неустойчивое решение, старшие коэффициенты близки к нулю: `[ 8.82537534e-07, -4.11937835e-06, -1.89266032e-05, 1.04049955e-04, 6.36226282e-05, -6.92743356e-04,  1.00037952e+00,  2.00078935e+00, 2.99954647e+00,  3.95610000e+00]`

Значение 192.347 результат линейной аппроксимации методом наименьших квадратов. Устраивает? Почему?

И тот, и другой ответы верные. А также верны ещё бесконечное число других вариантов. Например, вариант 22717.405125233458 - это аппроксимация экспонентой `5.684056421094344 *e^(-0.7539292289807961*x)`

Всё зависит от того, как вы собираетесь аппроксимировать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Аппроксимация экспонентой, полиномом, линейной функцией*

В вашем случае точки хорошо ложатся на прямую. Может быть достаточно линейной аппроксимации?

Comment: Вообще-то ТС именно это и спрашивал, как я понимаю - линейную аппроксимацию МНК, ему, похоже, нужен сам код...